# How to get result from last SQL statement in Slick

Tags: sql, sql-server, scala, slick

I have the following Scala code:

```
db.run(sql"""
  DECLARE @Ids TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE CLUSTERED (ID));
  INSERT INTO @Ids VALUES ...;
  SELECT A.* FROM SomeTable AS A
  INNER JOIN @Ids AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
""".as[Dto])
```

In this case Slick (3.2.1) returns result of `INSERT` (number of affected rows).

How can I get data from `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Slick can't do that, however the other way is to disable output of sql updates:

```
db.run(sql"""
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Ids TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE CLUSTERED (ID));
  INSERT INTO @Ids VALUES ...;
  SELECT A.* FROM SomeTable AS A
  INNER JOIN @Ids AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;
""".as[Dto])
```